# What is the inverse of a $1 \times 1$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, inverse

> What is the inverse of a $1 \times 1$ matrix?

I came across this question while studying the inverse of matrices.

If we have a $1 \times 1$ matrix, does it have an inverse? What could it be?

Comment: There is a very natural isomorphism between the real numbers and $M_1(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let be $A\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times 1}$. Then for $a\in\mathbb{R}$ we can write $A=(a)$. The matrix is invertible if there exists a matrix $B\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times1}$ such that $AB=(1)$. Insteat of choosing $B$ you can choose $b\in\mathbb{R}$ and identify $B=(b)$. We get
$$
(1)=AB=(a)(b)=(ab).
$$
You see that it is a special and simple situation. If $a\neq 0$ you can choose $b=\frac1a$ and you got your inverse matrix.

If $(a)=A\neq (0)$ your matrix is invertable with $A^{-1}=\left(\frac1a\right)$.

Answer (score 3):

if $a \neq 0$, $$\frac1a \times a = 1$$

Do you see the solution?